# Select Uniq rows from two columns according to given user in MySql

Tags: mysql, select

I am creating a chat system where my database is looks like

```
from  to  msg  date
----  -- ----  -----------------
a     b   hi    12-3-15 12:04:21
b     a   hi    12-3-15 12:12:21
c     b   hi    12-3-15 12:14:21
d     b   hi    12-3-15 12:14:21
a     b   msg1  12-3-15 12:12:21
a     b   msg2  12-3-15 12:50:23
a     b   msg3  12-3-15 13:44:21
b     a   msg1  12-3-15 15:12:21
b     e   hi    12-3-15  15:32:21
b     c   hi    12-3-15 16:12:21
```

I am trying make a query that returns last message sent by use 'b' or last message received by use 'b' and output like

```
Actor b
----
c
e
a
d
```

I have written a query

```
(SELECT `to`
      , `from` 
 FROM databaseTable 
 WHERE from = 'b' 
 ORDER BY date desc) 

UNION 

(SELECT `to`
      , `from` 
 FROM databaseTable 
 WHERE to = 'b'
 ORDER BY date desc )
```

but it is not returning what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
select distinct `to` as ActorB
from
(
    select * from
    (
        SELECT `to`,`date` 
        FROM databaseTable 
        WHERE from = 'b'
        UNION 
        SELECT  `from` , `date`
        FROM databaseTable 
        WHERE to = 'b'
    ) temp
    ORDER BY date desc
) temp
```

Above query should work.

Answer (score 0):

This should return the last message sent or received by b.  But I am probably missing something from your question because this does not match your expected output.

```
 (SELECT `to`
          , `from` 
     FROM databaseTable 
     WHERE from = 'b' OR to= 'b'
     ORDER BY date desc) 
  LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: i started solution with the same query but reached no were .